# How can I get the address of xlsx cell containing provided value?

Tags: c#, excelpackage

I have a prepared dictionary in c# and xlsx file with filled columns. I need to find the column's and row's indexes if the cell contains the value provided from a dictionary.

I am using ExcelPackage and ExcelWorksheet.
Dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ExcelColumnsMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"property name", "column name"}
}
```

XLS

```
var excelFile = new FileInfo(importFileFullPath);
 using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];           
            }
```

And here I wonder how can i find the cell indexes with provided data. I'd like to see an example with any string or something.
Thank you for help!

Comment: What library are you using?  What code do you have?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem.  We would like to help you, but you need to show us that you have attempted to code a solution first.

Comment: I'm curious why there is no code in the question pertaining to loading the spreadsheet?  Do you have any code loading the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand what you want to do very well but this is a methode that search for a value in an xlsx file and returns the line and the column if found.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; //you should add the reference to that library for it to work

public Tuple<int, int> search(string Providedvalue)
{
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    Excel.Range range;

    string str;
    int rCnt;
    int cCnt;
    int rw = 0;
    int cl = 0;
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("path/exemple.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
    rw = range.Rows.Count;
    cl = range.Columns.Count;

    bool found = false;
    for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw && found == false; rCnt++)
    {
            for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= cl && found == false; cCnt++)
            {
                dynamic x = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                str = x.ToString();
                if (Providedvalue == str)
                {
                    int line = rCnt;
                    int column = cCnt;
                    return new Tuple<int, int>(line, column);
                }
            }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome, don't hesitate to ask if you need something